# Check for existence of a related object in a Case queryset statement?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to annotate a queryset with a related object, if that object exists, or with another field if it doesn't:

```
#models.py

class MyModel(Model):
  f1 = ForeignKey(MyRelated, related_name='f1')
  f2 = ForeignKey(MyRelated, related_name='f2', null=True)

#queryset

MyModel.objects.annotate(
  f=Case(
    When( *something* ,then=F('f2')),
    default=F('f1')
  )
)
```

What I need to know is what to put in in place of `*something*` to check if the foreign key exists or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rubber ducked this one out immediately:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
  f=Case(
    When(f2__isnull=False ,then=F('f2')),
    default=F('f1')
  )
)
```